# SVG bump point when animated line hover it

Tags: animation, svg, interaction

below i create a simple fiddle with svg animation:

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
<line x1="10" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10"style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0); stroke-width:1">
<animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 10 10" to="360 10 10" dur="7.5s"  repeatCount="indefinite" />
</line>
<circle cx="5" cy="5" r="1" style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"/>
<circle cx="15" cy="15" r="1" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);"/>
</svg>
```

My question is: is there a way that I can make blue and red point bump (change their  color for example) when red line hover them?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution: I'm creating a mask with the line. There are 2 extra circles (`fill:gold`) that are masked by the line.

I'm putting the animated line inside a `<g stroke="red">` because I want the used line to be white.

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewbox="0 0 20 20">

<circle cx="5" cy="5" r="1" style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);" />
<circle cx="15" cy="15" r="1" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);"/>

<mask id="mask">
<use xlink:href="#L" style="stroke:white"/>
</mask>
<g stroke="red">
<line id="L" x1="10" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10" >
  <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 10 10" to="360 10 10" dur="7.5s"  repeatCount="indefinite" />
</line>
</g>
<g style="fill:gold;mask: url(#mask)"> 
<circle cx="5" cy="5" r="1" />
<circle cx="15" cy="15" r="1"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Today we answered different questions :=)

Comment: aha... svg mask. thanks, i'll give it a try ASAP. I guess that i can apply other changes too - for example change circle size or transparency? Some kind of radar effect.

Comment: and one add question: did you think that mask effect can be spanned in time? Mean - red line hover in, mask apply, red line hover out, mask removed after 1 sec? I'm so sorry that i'm on phone now, can't wait to try your solution.

Comment: I would need to understand why do you need to remove it.

Comment: To preserve visual attention. My goal is to achieve something like a radar image where it has a similar effect. The user must see a "trace" from the object through which the red line has passed for another 1-2 seconds

Comment: How about changing the use's stroke-width? `<use xlink:href="#L" style="stroke:white;stroke-width:3"/>`